Message doesn't get displayed
So I am creating a login form with php and html, for some reason that I can't understand the message when user doesn't use the right credentials doesn't show up.
function login_user(){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = escape_string($_POST['password']);
    
        $query = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password }' ");
        confirm($query);
    
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
            set_message("Your Password or Username are wrong");
            redirect("login.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            redirect("admin");
        }
    }
}

function display_message() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['message'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }
}

function set_message($msg){
    if(!empty($msg)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $msg;
    } else {
        $msg = "";
    }
}

Here is what I use in a diffent php file to diplay the message.
<h2 class="text-center bg-warning"><?php display_message(); ?></h2>

I have tried to displayed in somewhere else but still nothing, also tried to comment the
unset($_SESSION['message']);

to see if it display something but nothing.

Don't rely on string escaping functions to prevent SQL injection, they alone are not sufficient. Instead, always use prepared statements with bound parameters. See this page and this post for some good examples.

Never store plain text passwords. Instead use password_hash() and password_verify().

Also, never ever modify/clean a user's password. It will change the intended password and may not match when you go to check it. The password functions Alex mentioned will hash the password so it can be securely stored.

Step 1: In the file that displays the message, run var_dump($_SESSION); to verify what's in the session.

Make sure all the scripts start with session_start();. Check your log for "Headers already sent" warnings, as this can interfere with sending the session cookie.

@AlexHowansky Your comments are not helpful to the OP. They will learn those things in time. Right now, they are obviously just playing around with PHP.

@PaulAllsopp - Pointing out big security issues in someone's code (specially when they are starting out) will always be helpful. Isn't it better that people learn to write safe code from the start? To make it second nature? "Fixing" insecure code after the fact can make it much harder and require big rewrites, while making it easier to miss places. Writing code safely should be a part of the planning, not an after thought. And pointing it out here also speaks to a larger audience (like future visitors), not just the OP.

Redirects while debugging something can lead to missing errors and warnings, and I'd strongly recommend avoiding that (unless you are debugging the redirects themselves). Sometimes just screaming with die('SUCCESS') and die('FAIL') can be more helpful.

@M.Eriksson No, it is not. Most newbies don't end up using a language because of this. They ask a simple question and get told to change this, that, and the other, and end up saying "This is too much!" Get them going, get their code working, and point them to some better practices. But simply pointing out the failures in their code does nothing whatsoever for their drive and enthusiasm.

@PaulAllsopp - I would like a source on "most newbies don't end up using a language because of this". If warning a new developer about security issues in their code just because they didn't ask specifically about that would result in them stop programming, I'm fine with that. Less risk of my, and others, personal data gets leaked. I am always grateful (as I was when I was a "newbie" with this) when people points out flaws or improvement points in my code. I've also written some bad code in my career because no one told me. I didn't know better.

@PaulAllsopp fully agree with M. Eriksson. It's never too early to get into good habits. A bigger issue here is that, in 2024, someone still taught the OP to write code in this insecure way, and/or they somehow thought that writing a login system, with all its pitfalls, was a good beginner project. It's not difficult to do it properly in terms of the SQL queries, and it increases reliability and reduces the chances of silly, frustrating, hard-to-debug SQL syntax errors caused by interpolated values. So there's literally no good reason for anyone to do it this way at any stage.
